# How can I write a front-end LLVM pass to insert an instruction at the beginning/end of every BasicBlock?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I tried using AllocaInst and inserted it in the end of a given BB as follows:

```
bool runOnBasicBlock(BasicBlock &BB) override {
// BB is the address to a BasicBlock instance
    errs() << BB.getName() << '\t';
    BasicBlock *pb=&BB;
    AllocaInst* pa = new AllocaInst(Type::getInt32Ty(getGlobalContext()), 0, "data");
    pb->getInstList().push_back(pa); //Inserts pa in the end of basic block pb

    //errs() << "\tstarts at\t" << i << "\tends at \t" << j << '\n';
    return false;
    }
```

I was succesfully able to link and create my LLVMBasicBlock.so file. But when I run it to transform a sample .bc file, it is throwing segmentation fault while it's working on %data.

Answer (score 0):

The constructors for LLVM instructions include a parameter for where to be inserted.  This parameter has a default of NULL, which you used in your code example.  For the AllocaInst, one of its constructors takes a basic block to insert at the end of:

```
AllocaInst (Type *Ty, Value *ArraySize, const Twine &Name, BasicBlock *InsertAtEnd)
```

My first recommendation would be to use the functionality provided for inserting instructions.

Second, AllocaInst takes a `Value* ArraySize`, which you are providing as 0.  0 is probably being coerced into a Value* of NULL.  You probably want to create a [ConstantInt](http://www.llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ConstantInt.html) of the appropriate number instead.  ConstantInt inherits from Value, so LLVM will safely coerce it.

Comment: Is it not possible to do using push_back(pa) instead of the functionality provided within allocainst?